# Can't get asp.net MVC4 DropDownList() to have a preset value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I didn't really see any answer on SO on how to do this via the ViewBag. (I know we all hate the ViewBag, and I should user a ViewModel. Not my question though, I need to know how to do it without setting up the ViewModel stuff).

Here is my controller set up for the GET request of the page:

```
var states = Ctx.States.ToList()
            .Select(state => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = state.Name,
                Value = state.Name
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();

ViewBag.SelectedStateOne = new SelectList(
                        states, 
                        "Text", 
                        "Value", 
                        user.Applicant.FinancialAidInformation.FinancialAidContacts
                        .ElementAtOrDefault(0).Address.State.Name);

ViewBag.SelectedStateTwo = states;
```

I am setting up the viewbag two different ways. Both ways seem to bind the drop down correcly, and post back the selected value correctly. But when I come back the the page the default selection is not what the value is in the database.

In my View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedStateOne", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedStateTwo", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Same drop down, but showing both to avoid confusion I guess.  I thought that what I am doing with the SelectedStateOne viewbag data is the right way to set the default value, but no dice. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you want to specify a default value, using `SelectList` is the simpler approach, so let's use that.

Firstly, your original query is unnecessary.  A `SelectList` can be built using an `IEnumerable<T>`, which means you don't have to project onto `SelectListItem`s first.  So this:

```
var states = Ctx.States.ToList()
            .Select(state => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = state.Name,
                Value = state.Name
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

becomes:

```
var states = Ctx.States.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Now you can simply assign the list to the `ViewBag` using your `Name` property instead:

```
// Removed the long type name for clarity
ViewBag.SelectedStateOne = new SelectList(states, "Name", "Name", YourSelected.State.Name);
```

The call in the view remains the same:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedStateOne", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If it still doesn't select the correct item, double check to ensure that `YourSelected.State.Name` exists in your `states` list.

Comment: Works great, AND, you cleaned up my code a little. Thanks for being awesome.